# Is there something similar to async.waterfall but for errors?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a script that the next function only need to be executed if the previous has failed.

Is there something like this? I don't want to chain all the functions coz will be hard to debug.

Comment: You have a callback (the last one) in the `async.js` library specifically for error handling. You just need to check for error parameter.

Comment: I know that. The problem is that I have a list of 20 functions to be executed in sequence. The next one only needs to be executed if the previous one has failed...

Comment: If you pass, to the specific callback of one of your functions an `error` as the first argument, the execution is going to stop and the `waterfall` callback function will be executed. What I mean is: you can prevent the other functions to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick I've used for this scenario is to return "done" in first argument of the callback:

```
async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    if (doneWithWaterfall) {
      return callback('done', 1);  // optional 2nd argument
    }
    callback(null);
  },
  function(callback){
    if (doneWithWaterfall) {
      return callback('done', 2);   // optional 2nd argument
    }
    callback(null);
  }
], function(err, result) { 
  if (!err || err === 'done') {
    console.log(result); // result is the 2nd argument of callback if returned
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```